# Google Assistant on raspberry pi device-model-id missing?

Tags: sdk, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, google-assistant-sdk

I'm very new here and have a question about Google Assistant on the raspberry pi. I've recently installed it and I *thought* I did everything right but when I run the demo I get thrown an error:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ google-assistant-demo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/env/bin/google-assistant-demo", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/assistant/library/__main__.py", line 119, in main
    raise Exception('Missing --device-model-id option')
Exception: Missing --device-model-id option
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the device model id as a flag when running the project.

`google-assistant-demo --device-model-id my-device-model`